# Shopify Liquid change settings for each loop iteration

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a question related to Shopify's Liquid.
I have an array (for example - url_links).

I do loop through ->

```
{% for link in url_links %}
 <a href="{{ link.url }}">Link</a>
 <img src="{{ section.settings.image }}">
{% endfor %}
```

If I have {{ section.settings.image }} and I upload image, then it is the same for each link.
Can I somehow make editable from page editor image for each loop item?

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't use blocks inside the section? Eg: You could create blocks that have two parameters, a link and an image, and then loop through the blocks to create your list?

Comment: The problem is that there should be also optional dropdown list

Comment: Can you give more context on what you've tried so far?  I see that you are using section settings to get an image - can you share (roughly) what your section's `schema` looks like and where your `url_links` variable is coming from?